# How to get the public key ID/Fingerprint from a detatched signature in OpenPGP.js

Tags: openpgp.js

```ts
import * as openpgp from "openpgp";

let detatchedSignature = "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE----- insert signature here -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----";
openpgp.readSignature({
  armoredSignature: detatchedSignature,
}).then((sig: openpgp.Signature) => {
  let signingPublicKey = // whaaa??
});
```

According the the [typedefs file](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/openpgp.d.ts) the `verify` function needs the public key to test against, that makes sence. The problem is that I don't know what the public key might be.

I have a database of public keys that I can query by `keyID` or `fingerprint`, and according to [RFC 4880](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880) it is possible to get the fingerprint. The [typedefs for `openpgp.readSignature()`](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/openpgp.d.ts#L109) I can input a detached signature and get the promise of a [`signature`](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/openpgp.d.ts#L112), but the object doesn't provide the fingerprint.

So how can I get the fingerprint or ID of the public key that created a signature using `OpenPGP.js`? Do I need to ask the user for the public key or can I just get it from the signature?

Answer (score 0):

After copying/pasting this thread on [`OpenPGPjs`'s issue tracker](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues) I got [this response](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/1325#issuecomment-855846026) from another contributor who said it wasn't easily possible at that moment and suggested that I submit a PR. So I submitted [PR 1326](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/pull/1326) adding a `getIssuerIDs` function to the `Signature` class. [See example here](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/3645164a1aaaa916130eeb915d24311ff5aa4b1c/README.md#getting-the-ids-of-the-issuers-of-a-signature).